# xsl inside an html tag

Tags: html, xslt, tags

I have an XML like this:

```
<dataroot>
<element>
<color>#FF0FFF</color>
</element>
<element>
<color>#FF0000</color>
</element>
</dataroot>
```

And I need to put inside this tag on html:

```
<xsl:for-each select="dataroot/element">
<tr style="background-color:{.};"> <xsl:value-of select="color" />
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it does not work. I tried to use it as attribute also but it did not work.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="dataroot/element"> 
    <tr style="background-color:{color};"></tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```